# Get Focused Window in WPF to front

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a UserControl and a DialogResult Window that opens as a result of a button click in the UserControl. When both of them are open and when the user clicks the UserControl, I want to bring the UserControl to front and when he is on the UserControl and selects the DialogWindow I want to get Dialog Window to front. Please help. Please provide some sample code. Thanks.

Comment: If your dialog window is shown modally (via `ShowDialog`) then that window must be closed before another window in your application can receive focus. It sounds like you want to show the dialog window non-modally so that you can switch focus between the dialog window and the window containing the user control. In that case, you want to show the dialog window with the `Show` method instead of `ShowDialog`.

Comment: How does the **prism** tag relate to this question? You neither explain what Prism functionality do you use, nor ask how to solve your problem with Prism.

Comment: Sorry Im using bootstrapper where Im loading User Control in the Main Workspace Region and Dialog Window is called with Show() method on button click..

Comment: Hi Steven I have used the Show() method to open the Dialog Window but it dosent make any difference. The only thing is both Windows can operate parallely but then the Dialog overlaps with UserControl and even when the UserControl is focussed it is not brought to front.

Comment: @nikhil Are you sure that the `UserControl` is receiving focus (does it change colour or appearance, or display a blinking caret)? Have you tried setting focus to other controls in the dialog window: do they bring it to the front? What other controls are on your dialog window?

Comment: Hi Steven the userControl is getting focus. I have also tested out with GotFocus and LoastFocus Events. The control on the dialog result are Stackpaner, Grid, Canvas, DataGrid, Label and Combobox

Answer (score 0):

If it is coming up behind your other windows, on your DialogWindow.xaml.cs you can set

```
this.Topmost = true;
```

EDIT:
I assume your UserControl is hosted in a window itself. So now you have your 'main' window and your 'dialogWindow'.

To get your 'main' window to be topmost, you can get the parent window of your user control. In your UserControl.cs, you can have this on your PreviewLeftMouseButtonDown event

```
        Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
        parentWindow.Topmost = true;
```

Comment: Ok For Dialog Window on PreviewLeftMouse Button down Im saying this.Topmost = true; But this property is not available for the UserControl. So when PreviewLeftMouse Button down for UserControl, I want to set the same property. How do I do it in case of User Control. Thanks.

Comment: Edited post above to answer this

Comment: I tried it but it dosent work for some reason. Still the Dialog loads up on top of mainwindow and after I click anytime on mainwindow, it dosent load on top. But when I have a break point it seems to be executing that line.